# Hadoop 2.2.0 fails running start-dfs.sh with Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I have a work in progress installation of Hadoop in Ubuntu 12.x. I already had a `deploy` user which I plan to use to run hadoop in a cluster of machines. The following code demonstrate my problem basically I can `ssh olympus` no problems but `start-dfs.sh` fails doing exactly that:

```
deploy@olympus:~$ ssh olympus
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-45-generic x86_64)

    * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Mon Feb  3 18:22:27 2014 from olympus
deploy@olympus:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/dev/java/1.7.0_51

deploy@olympus:~$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [olympus]
olympus: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
```

Comment: have you configured you ssh server and hadoop configuration ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can edit **hadoop-env.sh** file and set JAVA_HOME for Hadoop

Open the file and find the line as bellow

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/j2sdk1.6-sun
```

Uncomment the line And update the java_home as per your environment

This will solve the problem with java_home.

Comment: An odd thing about this, you have to explicitly set this value in **hadoop-env.sh** file. It won't read from you environment...I don't understand this.

Comment: I was facing the same issue and putting the hard coded path of JAVA_HOME worked for me.

Comment: I had JAVA_HOME set already on my shell, but wasnt getting picked up.This solution worked fine with Hadoop 3.0 on Ubuntu trusty64.

Answer (score 12):

Weird out of the box bug on Ubuntu. The current line

```
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
```

in /etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh should pick up java home from host but it doesnt.

Just edit the file and hard code the java home for now.

Comment: Yeah this is weird. If the same user invoking 'start-dfs.sh' has a valid $JAVA_HOME... why wouldnt that be picked up?  Is there something in the script thats causing it to be run as the 'hadoop' user instead of the current one logged into bash?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can edit `/etc/environment` to include:

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/[YOURJAVADIRECTORY]`

This makes `JAVA_HOME` available to all users on the system, and allows `start-dfs.sh` to see the value. My guess is that `start-dfs.sh` is kicking off a process as another user somewhere that does not pick up the variable unless explicitly set in `hadoop-env.sh`.

Using `hadoop-env.sh` is arguably clearer -- just adding this option for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Hadoop start-up script `/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` by setting the `JAVA_PATH` explicitly.

For example:
Instead of `export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}`, do

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64/jre`

This is with the Java version, java-1.8.0-openjdk.

Answer (score 0):

I have hadoop installed on `/opt/hadoop/` and java is installed into `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` 
At the end adding this into the bash profile files, I solved any problem.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle  
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native 
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGERi=INFO,console
export HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER=INFO,NullAppender
export HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER=INFO,NullAppender
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_PREFIX=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_LOG_DIR=/tmp
```